# How do I parse values of union and list types in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have an XML Schema that includes data types that use `<xs:union>` and `<xs:list>`. Here is an extract:

```
<xs:simpleType name="mixeduniontype">
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:boolean xs:int xs:double xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="valuelist">
  <xs:list itemType="xs:double"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And here is a sample XML fragment:

```
<value>42</value>
<value>hello</value>

<values>1 2 3.2 5.6</values>
```

The two upper `<value>` elements are unions, and the lower `<values>` element is a list.

My question is, how do I parse an `<xs:union>` and `<xs:list>` elements in .NET?

How do I check which data type the value in a union element has?

How do I extract the elements in the a list element and convert them to a C# list?

Is there built-in support in **System.XML** for this kind of parsing, or do I need to write the parsing code myself?

Comment: Have you considered using `xsd.exe` for class generation from schema?

Comment: use XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

Hoping for a better answer but,

I think you need to write it yourself.

If you want a generic parser for all possible instances of `xs:list` and `xs:union` you have a more difficult problem but for your specific schema, its fairly straight forward.

```
//assuming parent is the containing node

//Parse your 'valuelist'
var newList = new List<double>();
foreach (string s in parent.XElement("values").value.Split(" ")) //should check for nulls here
{
    double value = 0.0;
    if (double.TryParse(s, value))
    {
        newList.Add(value);
    }
    else
    {
        \\throw some format exception
    }
}

//Parse your 'mixeduniontype'
Type valueType = typeof string;
double doubleValue;
int intValue;
boolean booleanValue;

var stringValue = parent.XElement("value").First();

if (double.TryParse(stringValue, doubleValue))
{
    valueType = typeof double;
}
else
{
    if (int.TryParse(stringValue, intValue))
    {
        valueType = typeof int;
    }
    else
    {
        if (bool.TryParse(stringValue, booleanValue))
             valueType = typeof boolean;
    }
}
```